# Does a climate change big data provider exist?

Tags: climate-change, data-analysis

Does a big data provider (Like a Bloomberg, which is the world's leading financial data provider) exist which includes **ALL** the possible informations and parameters about climate change or in general about environment?

Comment: i think you need to change this question to where can i find reliable climate data,or something similar.

Comment: Please specific which type of data you are looking for: measurements of the current state of the system (co2 measurements, measured temperature rise, ..), model predictions of climate change (with respect to physical, chemical, and biological parameters), socio-economical impacts of climate change?

Comment: I wrote 'Like a Bloomberg' because I mean a very general data provider: how much does every company contribute to climate change, live news about environment topics, and pretty much all the parameters you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, *ALL the possible informations and parameters about climate change or in general about environment* is way way too broad. You will have to limit your question to a far more specific query. I seriously doubt you want ALL information, if that ranges from nitty gritty details of isotope ratios per milimeter of ice core to large scale statistical fluctuations in the jet stream.

Comment: And take a look at [OpenData.se], what you need may be there already. Questions for material you're looking for are on-topic on both sites (but [do not crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), choose).

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data/10155 may or may not be helpful

Comment: The answer is "no" ;-)
As others have said, you'll need to be much more specific about what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to catch a 60 minutes [interview piece on Bloomberg](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/michael-bloomberg-net-worth-is-47b-how-will-he-use-it/)... while the interview was honestly more adulation than journalism, they showed a little bit about the Bloomberg Terminal at times which really caught my eye.  ([The transcript](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/michael-bloomberg-net-worth-is-47b-how-will-he-use-it/) has a few details, but the video would hopefully be more thorough... looks like you can watch the full interview [here](https://www.cbs.com/shows/60_minutes/video/ulLlK3UFLU4r9kep_SHY8B0sUHcxshUe/bloomberg/) if you happen to have the pay CBS All Access service).  It really seemed like it was a remarkable tool at gathering diverse data together into sort of like a master dashboard or real-time encyclopedia, and making it very flexible and easily consumable.  It seems to be something that could be of amazing use, and I suggest folks look into to get an idea of what can be done with technology applied well, it may spark some creativity and reshape views.  Knowing what that software is about, the questions seems a very valid one, as I'd always be eagerly on the look out for such a comprehensive and thorough collection of unified data on the topic of climate change.

But that said, I'm quite sure the answer is a firm **no**; such a comprehensive source of climate data likely doesn't exist.

Bloomberg has really done what they've done because the information they're collecting is worth huge value in the markets, and they can then sell that utility for great prices.

But there's likely not such money in most other topics, including much of scientific data.  If there were such tools developed in science, one would think they may well focus more on aggregating and simplifying subjects that are clearly more lucrative, such as genetic data, or detailed medical records, or, if venturing nearer our fields here, oil/mineral data, or perhaps maybe meteorological data, rather than climate data and one particular prong of it (how it is changing/why).

Yes, there's a lot of attention in climate change these days, and so research may well be funded a bit more than it used to be.  But the focus in the study is still really on developing conclusions to convince the public and policy makers, rather than on generating some tangible asset/information that owners could practically apply to thereby excel in some lucrative market field.  While there are indeed some industries with significant connection to the topic, such as energy generation and pollution credits, their focus is generally on gathering the very specific information they need (e.g., wind/solar data/modeling for renewable energy siting, forecasting politics for predicting policy shifts in generation balance and pollution controls, etc).  I've not known anyone to forsee any giant particular financial use of drawing all the climate change data together.  [Then again I wouldn't have imagined that a group like Bloomberg's would have recognized the potential and then had such technological vision and success in culling such wide-ranging access to make something like there tool... until I saw the story)  But it just doesn't seem there are the obvious grand benefits to doing similar for climate change.

The closest I can think of would be [IBM's initiative towards meteorological big data](https://www.zdnet.com/article/ibms-new-launch-pairs-geoscope-aims-to-be-search-for-geospatial-big-data/).  Others sites like NOAA's [Climate Data Online](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/) have a few items, and [this open data collection](https://discuss.okfn.org/t/climate-change-datasets/1593/4) appears it may also offer a good starting point.  But overall, it may well more often still come down to tracking down separate specific datasets yourself when getting into more of the specifics.  Of course you're in a good place here to try asking if you decide there's something specific you're after!
But in terms of company by company data, I expect being related to corporate affairs, there's more hope in finding that using Bloomberg itself than in finding another such source built around this specific subject.  There likely are websites that monitor news stories and such.  And there may be at least some separate piecemeal datasets findable on specific impacts to people/countries/industries/etc.

I've indeed found it frustrating for years that even as piles of articles and webpages have been made focusing on climate change, there really still aren't fantastic options that allow typical folks and experts in other subjects to quickly and easily explore the past and current data very flexibly and graphically, more in line with it appears Bloomberg's software is.  Yes, it's still possible for even novices to dig in with enough work, as even [this question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/15039/how-to-best-visualize-temperature-increase-due-to-climate-change-using-ghcn-da) here at ESSE did a great job of.  But we have miles to go of improvement in such true accessibility.

I do hope if you unfortunately have to go through the painstaking effort to source and gather such data, that you'll take the time to give back as you're able, to help others who come after you!  We really only do advance anywhere by the progress of those who came before us.

Best of luck, and hope the input was at least of some help to you or others somewhere along the way at least.